# Locus of solution of an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parametric, nonlinear-system, locus

I have an ODE system
$$
\ddot p = \frac{ p \left( {2p - 4} \right) }{{p - 4}}{{\dot q }^2 } \\
\ddot q  = \frac{{3p - 8}}{{p - 4}}\dot q \dot p
$$

Short of finding closed-form expressions for $p\left( t \right)$ or $q\left( t \right)$, I have made a guess at a closed-form expression for a locus $p\left( q \right)$, namely,

$$p\left( q  \right) = \frac{8}{{5 + 3\cos {\textstyle{3 \over 2}}q }}$$

(I arrived at this purely by trying to guess a function that gives a good eyeball match to a numerical solution when plotted, for initial conditions $p_0=1$, $q_0=0$, $\dot p_0=0$, $\dot q_0=1$.)

Of course, if the ODE was in a form where the derivative of $p$ was taken with respect to $q$, I could just plug my guess into the equation and see if it holds.  But both $p$ and $q$ are functions of a parameter $t$.  In this case, is there any way to test my guess?

Comment: Change p and q in tour ODE to P and Q.  Let  Q(t)=t and P(t)= p(t) where p(t) is the function p  in your guess.What is the context and how did you make this guess?

Comment: I edited the question to address your comment.  Thanks for this suggestion.  Unfortunately I don't understand how this idea is different from conjecturing a solution (q(t)=t, p(t)=[the guess above]) and substituting those into the ODE to check if they solve it.  And based on plotting the numerical solution, I am confident that this (q(t),p(t)) pair does not solve the ODE.  Or in other words, how do I justify letting q(t)=t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think that your guess is not exact (may be it is an approximate on a range). This can be verified with the method below :
[image]

The analytic solution involves complicated integrals. The first one can be expressed on a closed form involving only elementary functions, but as a big formula (not written on the page below). The next one is even more complicated and more likely cannot be expressed on a closed form. I think that one have to use numerical calculus to solve the ODE system.

[image]

Comment: Not unfortunate at all!  I was really much more curious about how to decide the guess than hoping it is exact.  And for the second "extra" part that derives an expression for q(p), it will take me more time to step through all of it in detail but it looks like there are several good techniques that I can benefit from.  Thank you for this very thorough answer.